# "SparkException: Job aborted" when Koalas writes to Azure blob storage

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, spark-koalas

I am using Koalas (pandas API on Apache Spark) to write a dataframe out to a mounted Azure blob storage.  When calling the df.to_csv API, Spark throws an exception and aborts the job.

Only a few of the stages seem to fail with the following error:

```
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
permission.
```

I am handling the data with Databricks on Azure using PySpark.  The data products reside in a mounted Azure Blob storage.  A service principle for databricks was made and is set as "contributer" to the Azure storage account.

When looking into the storage account, I notice that some of the first blobs were already prepared in the directory.  Moreover, I am able to place the output in the blob storage using a "pure Python" approach with pandas.  Therefore, I doubt that it has to do with authorization issues for Databricks.

This is the minimal coding example of what I used to create the error.

```
<Test to see if the blob storage is mounted>
# Import koalas
import databricks.koalas as ks
# Load the flatfile
df = ks.read_csv('/dbfs/spam/eggs.csv')
# Apply transformations
# Write out the dataframe
df.to_csv('/dbfs/bacon/eggs.csv')
```

Since there are many facets to this issue, I am uncertain where to start:

- Authorization issue between the blob storage and Databricks
- Incorrect setup of the Databricks cluster
- Applying the wrong API method
- Issue with the file content

Any leads on where to look?

Comment: Are you connecting databricks with Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake Gen2?

Comment: To an azure Blob Storage